# How to solve $\partial_x\partial_y u = k u$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I stumble upon this one not for the first time, and it looks annoyingly simple. However, I still have no idea, how to find its general solution (except for guessing it, but I didn't succeed).

$u$ is a two variable real function, $k$ is a real constant

Comment: PDE is linear, so maybe try separation of variables

Comment: Yes, if I assume $u$ to be $f(x)g(y)$, I indeed get a solution. I'll have $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = k\frac{g'(y)}{g(y)},$ which means $f'(x)=c_1f(f)$,$g'(y)=c_2g(y)$ with $c_1 = kc_2$. It leads only to $u=Ce^{c_1x+c_2y}$, but it is not general enough, I guess? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your treatment of the separated case is incorrect. You should obtain ${f'(x)\over f(x)}\cdot{g'(y)\over g(y)}=k$.

Comment: Oh, right, my bad. But even turned upside down, it wouldn't help. I mean, it leads to the same $u$, but with $c_1c_2=k$. Unless I should not have assumed both of these fractions to be constant in the first place. I'm not actually sure, if I should, it's just intuitive. What else can be done then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial y}=ku$$
If you intend to solve it with the method of separation of variables you will obtain :
$$u=C\:e^{\lambda x+\frac{k}{\lambda}y}$$
with $C$ and $\lambda$ any constants.

Of course this is not the general solution, but only particular solutions.

Any linear combination of those particular solutions is a solution of the PDE.

Thus on discret form :
$$u(x,y)=\sum_\lambda C_\lambda\:e^{\lambda x+\frac{k}{\lambda}y}$$
where $C_\lambda$ are arbitrary constants.

Or on integral form :
$$u(x,y)=\int C(\lambda)\:e^{\lambda x+\frac{k}{\lambda}y}d\lambda$$
where $C(\lambda)$ is an arbitrary function.

The function $C(\lambda)$ has to be determined according to some boundary conditions (which are not specified in the wording of the question).